# Can i move Azure Compute Disk to a Storage Account using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have created a compute disk resource in Azure using ARM Template.Can i move that resource inside a storage account using ARM Templates so that it can be used as Unmanaged Data Disk.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

But you could use Azure Power Shell to copy managed disk to a storage account.

```
##create $SAS
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName shui -DiskName shuitest -DurationInSecond 3600 -Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName contosostorageav1 -StorageAccountKey 'YourStorageAccountKey' 
Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer 'vhds' -DestContext $destContext -DestBlob 'MyDestinationBlobName.vhd'
```

Comment: No i think there is no way of doing this using arm template

Comment: Yes, you are right. You could use Azure Power Shell to do this.

Comment: yes this script works but i wanted to use arm template as mentioned in the question

Comment: But I think it is impossible.